# Cannot open an existing text file in C using fopen()

Tags: c, file-io, text-files, fopen, dev-c++

My task is to read a text file and count how many words, characters and unique words there are in it, as well as to count how many words have 1, 2, ... , 30 letters. In the end, I must save the above statistics in another text file. The program was working well, but when I created the createHistFile() function, I compiled my project once again, but the program could not read it. I have also checked whether I have permission to read it and I tried to copy my code to an entirely new project, however none of these worked. I am using Dev-C++ on Windows XP.

I would really appreciate any help, because I can think no solution for this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LEN 30
#define MAX_NUM 30

void blankCharArray(char [][MAX_LEN + 1]);
int countChars(char *);
int countUniqueAndList(char *, char [][MAX_LEN + 1]);
int countWords(char *);
FILE *createFile(char *);
void createHistFile(char *, int, int, int, char [][MAX_LEN + 1]);
void createWordList( char *, char [][MAX_LEN + 1]);
void letterHist(char [][MAX_LEN + 1]);
void nameFile(char *);
FILE *readFile(char *);
void removePunctAndLower(char *);
int scanArray(char *, char text [][MAX_LEN + 1]);

// Names files.
void nameFile(char *fileName) { 
    printf("Dose to onoma tou arxeiou: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    printf("\n");
}

// Creates a file to write to.
FILE *createFile(char *fileName) { 
    FILE *filePtr;

    if ( ( filePtr = fopen(fileName, "w") ) == NULL ) {
        printf("Error: To arxeio %s den dimiourgithike.", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    return filePtr;
}

// Reads a file.
FILE *readFile(char *fileName) { 
    FILE *filePtr;

    if ( ( filePtr = fopen(fileName, "r") ) == NULL ) {
        printf("Error: To arxeio %s den diavastike.", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    return filePtr;
}

// Counts the words that are in the text file.
int countWords(char *fileName) { 
    int count = 0;
    char word[MAX_LEN + 1];
    FILE *filePtr;

    filePtr = readFile(fileName);

    while ( fscanf(filePtr, "%s", word) != EOF )
        count++;

    fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(filePtr);

    printf("To sinolo ton lexeon sto keimeno %s einai: %d\n", fileName, count);

    return count;
}

// Counts the number of characters there are in the text file.
int countChars(char *fileName) {
    int count = 0;
    char ch;
    FILE *filePtr;

    filePtr = readFile(fileName);

    while ( fscanf(filePtr, "%c", &ch) != EOF ) {
        if ( ch != ' ' )
            count++;
    }

    fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(filePtr);

    printf("To sinolo ton xaraktiron sto keimeno %s einai: %d\n", fileName, count);

    return count;
}

// Checks if a string (word) is in the array of strings called text.
int scanArray(char *word, char text[MAX_NUM][MAX_LEN + 1]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++) {
        if ( strcmp(word, text[i]) == 0)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void removePunctAndLower(char *word) {
    char *initPtr = word, *newPtr = word;

    while (*initPtr) {
       if ( ispunct(*initPtr) )
          initPtr++;
       else if ( isupper(*initPtr) ) {
          *newPtr = tolower(*initPtr);
          initPtr++;
          newPtr++;
       }
       else if (initPtr == newPtr) {
          initPtr++;
          newPtr++;
       }
       else {
          *newPtr = *initPtr;
          initPtr++;
          newPtr++;
      }
    }

    *newPtr = '\0';
}

// Counts the number of unique words in the text file and fills an array
// with those words.
int countUniqueAndList(char *fileName, char wordList[MAX_NUM][MAX_LEN + 1]) {
    int i, uniqueNum = 0;
    char word[MAX_LEN + 1];
    FILE *filePtr;

    filePtr = readFile(fileName);

    while ( fscanf(filePtr, "%s", word) != EOF ) {
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++) {
            removePunctAndLower(word);
            if ( scanArray(word, wordList) == 0 ) {
                strcpy( wordList[uniqueNum], word );
                uniqueNum++;
            }       
        }
    }

    fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(filePtr);

    printf("To sinolo ton diaforetikon lexeon sto keimeno %s einai: %d\n", fileName, uniqueNum);

    return uniqueNum;
}

// Creates an array that contains every word of the text file.
void createWordList(char *fileName, char wordList[MAX_NUM][MAX_LEN + 1]) {
    int i;
    char word[MAX_LEN + 1];
    FILE *filePtr;

    filePtr = readFile(fileName);

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++)
        if ( fscanf(filePtr, "%s", word) != EOF ) {
            removePunctAndLower(word);
            strcpy(wordList[i], word);
        }

    fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(filePtr);
}

// "Initializes" a char array with '\0' 
void blankCharArray(char arr[MAX_NUM][MAX_LEN + 1]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++)
        strcpy(arr[i], "");
}

// Prints how many words have 1, 2, ... , 30 letters to the console.
void letterHist(char wordList[MAX_NUM][MAX_LEN + 1]) {
    size_t i, t, count = 0;

    printf("\nIstogramma plithous grammaton ana lexi tou keimenou\n\n");
    for (i = 0; strcmp(wordList[i], "") != 0; i++)
        if ( strlen(wordList[i]) == 1 )
            count++;
    if (count != 0)
        printf("Oi lexeis pou exoun 1 gramma einai: <%d>\n", count);
    for (t = 2; t < 31; t++) {
        count = 0;
        for ( i = 0; strcmp(wordList[i], "") != 0; i++)
            if ( strlen(wordList[i]) == t )
                count++;
        if (count != 0)
            printf("Oi lexeis pou exoun %d grammata einai: <%d>\n", t, count);
    }
}

// Creates a file with the above statistics.
void createHistFile(char *fileName, int wordsNum, int charsNum, int uniqueNum, char wordList[MAX_NUM][MAX_LEN + 1]) {
    size_t i, t, count = 0;
    FILE *filePtr;

    filePtr = createFile(fileName);

    fprintf(filePtr, "To sinolo ton lexeon sto keimeno %s einai: %d\n", fileName, wordsNum);
    fprintf(filePtr, "To sinolo ton xaraktiron sto keimeno %s einai: %d\n", fileName, charsNum);
    fprintf(filePtr,"To sinolo ton diaforetikon lexeon sto keimeno %s einai: %d\n\n", fileName, uniqueNum);

    fprintf(filePtr, "\nIstogramma plithous grammaton ana lexi tou keimenou\n\n");
    for (i = 0; strcmp(wordList[i], "") != 0; i++)
        if ( strlen(wordList[i]) == 1 )
            count++;
    if (count != 0)
        fprintf(filePtr, "Oi lexeis pou exoun 1 gramma einai: <%d>\n", count);
    for (t = 2; t < 31; t++) {
        count = 0;
        for ( i = 0; strcmp(wordList[i], "") != 0; i++)
            if ( strlen(wordList[i]) == t )
                count++;
        if (count != 0)
            fprintf(filePtr, "Oi lexeis pou exoun %d grammata einai: <%d>\n", t, count);
    }

    fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(filePtr);
}

int main(void) {
    int wordsNum, charsNum, uniqueNum;
    char inputFileName[MAX_LEN + 1], outputFileName[MAX_LEN + 1], wordList[MAX_NUM][MAX_LEN + 1], uniqueWordList[MAX_NUM][MAX_LEN + 1];

    blankCharArray(wordList);
    blankCharArray(uniqueWordList);

    nameFile(inputFileName);

    wordsNum = countWords(outputFileName);  
    charsNum = countChars(outputFileName);
    uniqueNum = countUniqueAndList(outputFileName, uniqueWordList);

    createWordList(outputFileName, wordList);
    letterHist(wordList);

    nameFile(outputFileName);


    printf("\n");
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to read the file? Are you getting an error message? Is your program acting as iff the file is empty without an error message? Are you getting erroneous results? Be specific.

Comment: filePtr in readFile function is NULL so the printf clause is activated and the program ends, although fileName doesn't appear the sentence, which is weird.

Comment: this line: 'while ( fscanf(filePtr, "%s", word) != EOF )'  1) will fail after the first loop because no facility has been used to get by the white space that stopped the prior fscanf()  suggest format string: " %s" (note leading space)  2) there is no facility to limit the amount of text input, so a buffer overflow can occur, resulting in undefined behavior,  which can/will lead to a seg fault event. suggest format string: " %99s" (note leading space and max length modifier

Comment: I don't know if that's the case because in previous compilations it worked perfectly and the number of words, chars etc. was spot on.

Comment: this line: 'if ( ch != ' ' )' words can be separated by any white space (including multiple white space characters) so need to implement a 2 state algorithm.  using  bool inWord=false.   When any white space is input, if inWord is true, then set inWord=false and process the word.  Otherwise set inWord = true.

Comment: just because an error  did not happen does not mean it should not be checked for.

Comment: placing multiple variables on a single line is a bad programming practice.  It makes documentation difficult, interferes with the operation of automated documentation tools and makes debugging more difficult.

Comment: I messed the words up again (English is not my native language). It works now. Thanks a lot @user3121023.

Comment: @user3629249 I am aware that I need to improve my program, but my main goal is for it to just work first. Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: regarding these lines: 'fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(filePtr);' why bother to call fseek() if the next code statement is fclose()"

Comment: The posted code causes the compiler to raise 9+ warnings.  Suggest enabling all warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, as a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')

Comment: 1) an array can be initialized with a single statement: 'memset( addressOfArray, 0x00, sizeofArray );' so no need for a new function.  2) checking if an array entry is used is simply: 'if( '\0' == array[x][y][0] ) so no need to call strcmp()

Comment: @user3629249 As for the fseek() call, I noticed that the cursor was at the EOF, so I had to move it back at the beginning otherwise charsNum and uniqueNum would be 0, because those functions' while loops would never materialize.